# Does List.subList keep a reference to the original list?

Tags: java

If I have a variable

```
LinkedList list
```

and repeatedly do the following to extract the tail of 'list'

```
// Some operation that adds elements to 'list'
// max_size = some constant
list = (LinkedList) list.subList(list.size()-max_size, list.size());
```

do I end up with a lot of references to the 'previous' list?

So basically what I'm trying to do here is to remove an initial segment of the list.

Is there a better way to remove an initial segment of a LinkedList?  I think the data structure of LinkedList should allow linear time (linear in the size of the initial segment to be removed) operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code will simply fail - the returned sublist *is not* a `LinkedList<T>`. Sample program:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("x");
        list.add("y");
        list = (LinkedList<String>) list.subList(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.SubList
    cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

It sounds like you should just be calling `removeFirst` as many times as you need to:

```
while (list.size() > maxSize) {
    list.removeFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When all else fails, consult the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and
>   toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is
>   backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list
>   are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

If you need to remove elements from the front of the list then you can just use `removeFirst`, and call it as many times as you need.

Comment: Actually he wants to remove the beginning of the list, so he should use `removeFirst()`.

Comment: You know, I couldn't really tell from how he phrased his question. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, quoting the JavaDoc of [`List.subList(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

> Returns a **view** of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The **returned list is backed by this list**, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

What you can do to avoid holding a reference to old list (and possibly creating a memory leak) is to create a new instance based on `subList`:

```
list = new ArrayList(list.subList(list.size()-max_size, list.size()));
```

That's it! The advantage of this approach compared to `removeFirst()` is that it will work with any `List` implementation - `removeFirst()` is defined in `LinkedList` only.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an initial segment of a list in Java, do:

```
list.subList(0, numElementsToRemove).clear();
```

This works because the sub-list is backed by the original list (as the Javadoc says) so the `clear()` is reflected through onto the range of the original.