# Limit number of list view items through array adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am using a list view to display user submitted comments. This is naturally backed by an `ArrayAdapter` for displaying. Now there can be many, many comments and I don't want that all the thousand comments are preserved in memory.

Do I really have to worry about this or does Android take care of this itself? If not, how can I best do this. The only strategy I came up with when a new comment is added:

- check size of the list
- remove one comment if it is `> threshold`
- add new comment
- clear adapter
- reassign list to adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with the other answer.  Sounds like you will be better off subclassing `BaseAdapter` to write your own custom adapter solution.  It's a bit more work but would be the preferable solution.  The moment you need to modify the behavior for one of the mutating methods of an `ArrayAdapter` is the moment you open yourself up to possible problems. It's also not recommended to track the list used to construct your `ArrayAdapter` backed solution. For one, there's no guarantee that the list reference remains the same...and in fact can change.  So it makes keeping your list in sync with `ArrayAdapter` rather difficult.

Also, I may be wrong, but I believe re-assigning a sublist to original list will fail. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516764/does-list-sublist-keep-a-reference-to-the-original-list).  You'd be better off just calling `items.remove(#);` to remove an item.

But otherwise, the general solution would be (within your custom adapter) is to always check the size of your list when adding. If over the threshold, remove an item.

Answer (score 0):

On your constructor, slice the list if it exceeds the limit.

```
public MyAdapter(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    sliceItems();
}

void sliceItems() {
    //sort items first
    if (this.items.size() > limit) {
      this.items = this.items.subList(0, limit);
    }
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
    this.items.add(item);
    sliceItems();
}
```

Comment: Cool, and what about when adding new items? Then I need to remove the last one and add a new one.

Comment: expose a addItem method. See revised answer.

Comment: addItem() will immediately slice off the added item.

Comment: @greenapps: Not necessarily. I have a comment on sliceItems that says "sort items".